# Why manage your own Sql Server ID column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, relational-database, primary-key

I recently started a new job and I am perplexed as to why the tables were designed this way. (in many databases) Is there someone who can give me a logical explanation?

Each table has a primary key/Id field. Example: EmployeeId (Integer)

Then to get the next id we actually need to query and update a table that manages all the keys for every table.

```
SELECT NextId 
FROM dbo.NextID 
Where TableName = 'Employees'
```

This makes life difficult, as you can imagine. The person who designed this mess has left, and the others just buy into this is the way you do things.

Is there some design flaw in MS SQL Identity columns?  I don't get it?  Any ideas?

Thanks for your input

Comment: I have a feeling it is to keep a unique ID across many tables/databases.

Comment: @Elias I thought the same thing, until I saw the `Where TableName = 'Employees'` clause.  This sounds terribly inefficient though... The only thing I can see it being for is sequential IDs, but that should be irrelevant

Comment: Mr. White, as pointed out, the few programmers here "just buy into this is the way things are done". Thanks for the "help"

Comment: Well... at least for the update part, you could possibly add some triggers to handle it and make your life simpler.

Comment: How old is the system?  It could have started on a platform that didn't have auto-increment IDs and has never been updated.

Comment: Good point ...Many apps are very old, started on MS Access 97, however there are new ones created in the last year.

Comment: Trigger is a great idea too, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The features/limitations of IDENTITY columns make them useful for generating surrogate keys in many scenarios but they are not ideal for all purposes - such as creating "meaningful", managed and/or potentially updateable identifers usable by the business; or for data integration or replication. Microsoft introduced the SEQUENCE feature as a more flexible alternative to IDENTITY in SQL Server 2008. In code written for earlier versions where sequences weren't available it isn't unusual to see the kind of scheme that you have described.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the person wanted no gaps in the ID column therefore he/she implemented this unnecessary process of getting next available id.

Maybe your Application depends on sequential Ids, either way it is not the way to go, Your application should not be dependant on sequential values. and no doubt Identity value is the way to go for this kind of requirement.

*Issue with Identity Column*

Yes there was an active bug in Identity column in Sql Server 2012. Identity Column taking big jumps when creating new identity values. Still it should not matter.